# Django ImportError: No module named... but module is visible in Project Interpreter settings

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

I am developing a Django app and I am experiencing a strange problem. I've installed a few modules using pip and I can see them in "project interpreter settings":

[image]

However, when I try to import any of these modules I get errors like this:

```
File "/Users/Franek/Documents/testy/testy/testysearch/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sumy.summarizers.text_rank import TextRankSummarizer
ImportError: No module named sumy.summarizers.text_rank
```

I am using `virtualenv`, but I don't think this can be an issue, because when I try to run some of these modules from console (bypassing Django) they work properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You say you can import these modules when you run Python on the console. Do you also run `manage.py` from the same console?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides Yes i do.

Answer (score 0):

Did u activate your virtualenv, with the command:

```
source <virtualenv_name>/bin/ativate
```

Comment: Yes I did. Btw. I'm using PyCharm and as you can see in my original post "project interpreter" is correctly set to 'virtualenv'

Answer (score 0):

Try set in pycharm Root directory by click right button of mouse on the main folder (folder which contain manage.py file) and click set as root directory.